# Drawing a gradient on a path

Tags: android, linear-gradients

I am using a [library](https://github.com/devadvance/circularseekbar) for a circular seek bar.

What I want to achieve is attached in an image. [image]

I was trying to - 
1. Draw the colors with a LinearGradient. The colors are not distributed properly.

```
// The positions are from the circle rect and hardcoded for this sample.
protected int[] mGradientColors = {
                0xFFF15155, // red
                0xFFFBB846,// yellow
                0xFF19B6F1, // blue
        };
protected LinearGradient mLineargradient = new LinearGradient(-320.5F
                    , -320.25F
                    , 320.5F
                    , 320.25F
                    , mGradientColors, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

2. I also have a separate image (PNG) of the gradient.
   Tried extracting Colors from the image using the Palette API, but I get individual colors from the Swatch objects. Not sure how to convert them to a gradient.

Comment: Hi @Salil, have you achieved this as I am also looking for the same. Any reference would be highly appreciated. Thanks